# Tasker: remove security lock when smartwatch is connected

Tags: security, bluetooth, tasker

So I just downloaded Tasker because it would be nice to remove the security code when I'm close to my phone (when my smartwatch is connected).

I have no experience with it so I thought you guys could help me :)

Anybody knows how to do this?

Comment: Which android version are you running on your device? Lollipop has trusted device feature which can unlock the phone.

Answer (score 0):

This is a partial answer because sadly, the bluetooth in my devices doesn't connect to each other automatically.

Once you're done with the device trigger (Profile) you have to create a task. Following can be one of the tasks to reach the objective in question:

Go to **TASKS → Enter a name → `+` → Code →Run Shell.** Under **Command** field, type:

```
input keyevent 26; input text pin/password; input keyevent 66
```

Note that as per this [manual](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html), `224`(in place of `26`) should work to awake the device but it worked out only on my Lollipop based ROM and not on Kitkat and JellyBean. Keyevent `26` and `66` are to toggle the wake/sleep state of device and simulate <kbd>Enter</kbd> respectively.

As I already mentioned in my comment, there shouldn't be a need for Tasker to do this in Lollipop, since the latter has a Smart Lock feature that will automatically unlock the device one the trusted device(Smartwatch here) is connected to bluetooth of your phone.